# Rails combine multiple columns in search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

In my application I have a customers model with three columns, `first_name`, `middle_name` and `last_name`. I have a method in the model that performs the search:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.search(search, user)
    if search
      .where('first_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
      .where(user: user)
    else
      where(user: user)
    end
  end

end
```

The problem with this search function is that it only allows searching by one of the three columns at a time.

For example, a customer has a first_name of "foo", a middle_name of "bar" and a last_name of "baz". Searching for "foo", "bar", or "baz" individually returns results, but "foo bar" or "bar baz" does not. 
What is the best way I can allow searching across all three columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can concat your `field`s in the database query like

**Updated:**

```
.where("concat_ws(' ' , first_name, middle_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

This should work for `foo`, `foo bar`, or `foo bar baz`
but not `foo baz`

If you want to support `foo baz` as well then

```
.where("first_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ?"\
       " OR last_name LIKE ? OR concat_ws(' ' , first_name, middle_name, last_name) LIKE ?"\
       " OR concat_ws(' ' , first_name, last_name) LIKE ?", 
       "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this code working. Does this require a certain database? I'm using sqlite for development.

Comment: apologies; I forgot to change single quote to double quote

Answer (score 1):

.where("first_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? or CONCAT(first_name, middle_name, last_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pg, you can try like this

```
def self.search(query)
    where(['phone ilike :query',
       'LOWER(name) ilike :query',
       'LOWER(email) ilike :query',
       'LOWER(address) ilike :query'].join(' OR '), {query: "%#{query}%" })
end
```